# Access fields of returned Java Object

Tags: java, class, object, xml-rpc

I made a simple client call to the XML-RPC WordPress API/Posts using a xml-rpc client and according to their documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.getPost) it returns a struct. How can i access the return values.

```
Here is a look at my code:
XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient("http://www.mywebsite.net/xmlrpc.php", false);

    String[] fields = new String[4];
    fields[0] = "post_id";
    fields[1] = "post_title";
    fields[2] = "post_date";
    fields[3] = "post_content";
    Object token = client.invoke("wp.getPost", new Object[]{"0","myusername", "mypassword", 1545, fields });
    System.out.println(token);
```

When I print use
     System.out.println(token);
I get the following out put:

{item_one=I am item number one, item_two=I am Item two...}

How can I access item_one and item_two?

Comment: That looks like a JSON string, which you would need to parse. What is the Class of the "Object" you have?

Comment: @djna Please see the updated post. I apologize for the lack of detail on the first time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit of information missing (what's the fully qualified name of XmlRpcClient?), but assuming that client.invoke actually returns just an Object and not something more specific that has accessor methods, you can parse the response using something like this:

```
Object token = client.invoke("wp.getPost", new Object[]{"0","myusername", "mypassword", 1545, fields });
String[] items = token.toString().split(",");
for (String item : items) {
    String[] parts = item.split("=");
    String key = parts[0];
    String value = parts[1];
    // do stuff with your keys and values here
}
```

Of course this isn't perfect code -- you may need to check for nulls, use String.trim(), etc, but it should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a true Java representation of the data returned, in that you don't have an object on which you can access

```
 token.item_one
```

rather you have a string containing a representation of a set - that is something that (in concept) from which you could retrieve an value by its name

```
 token.get("item_one")
```

This string format is probably JSON, which pretty much looks like JavaScript, and hence can represent quite complex data. In general you can have arrays of objects and objects containing objects (for example, a Customer might contain an Address object)

So you have two possibilities:

1). parse the string into a true Java representation such as one of the standard Java collection classes. You then use the get-by-name style I show above.

2). define a Java class that mimics the structure of the data and then  parse the string to fill out such an object, you can then use the "dot" form of access - you really have a Java Object representing the data.

In the first case there are suitable libraries such as [quickJson](https://code.google.com/p/quick-json/)

For the second you can use implementations of standards such as JAX/B, which tends to be more work as you may need to construct the target Java Class by hand. Enterprise Java runtimes will give you these facilities and perhaps tooling to help, or look at implementaitons such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). You will see that JAX/B hada focus on mapping from XML to Java, but tutorials such as [this](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-json-tutorials/) show how to work with JSON instead.

My guess is that the first option, simple parsing to a collection may be enough for you.